# Is it possible to calculate LUB on type level?

Tags: scala, types

I need to get least upper bound of two types given as parameters. Something like that:

```
class Holder[T] {
  type Shrink[S] = ???
}
```

where `???` generates some type expression that produces least upper bound for the `T` and `S` types. Something that looks like `LUB_Magic[T,S]`.

I tried many things but couldn't find any way to express it.

For example, if types `A` and `B` predefined then

```
final case class Solve() {
  val query = (x : Any) => x match {
    case a : A => a
    case b : B => b
  }
  type Q = query.type
}
```

would produce type based on the least upper bound.

But if I try to parametrize it like `class Solve[A,B]()` then the type would be `Any` instead of the least upper bound. Same goes with the [gist solution](https://gist.github.com/retronym/341475)

Is it ever possible to get least upper bound on type level?

Answer (score 1):

If your main goal is to have the right result type in `query`, then you can simply add implicit evidence for `A <:< C` and `B <:< C` to the invocation of `query`. I've grouped the both types of evidence into a class called `Lub` here:

```
class Lub[A, B, C](val ev1: A <:< C, val ev2: B <:< C)

object Lub {
  implicit def lub[C, A <: C, B <: C]: Lub[A, B, C] = 
    new Lub[A, B, C](implicitly, implicitly)
}
```

Now you can use it to ensure that `query` returns the right type of function:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

case class Solve[A: ClassTag, B: ClassTag]() {
  def query[C](implicit lub: Lub[A, B, C]): Any => C = {
    (x: Any) => x match {
      case a : A => lub.ev1(a)
      case b : B => lub.ev2(b)
    }
  }
}

val s1 = Solve[Int, Float]
val q1: Any => AnyVal = s1.query // typechecks
```

If you insist on having `q` as `val` and the least upper bound as a type member of `Solve` instead of inferring it at the call site, you could do something like this:

```
abstract class Solve2[A: ClassTag, B: ClassTag] {
  type C
  def query: Any => C
}

object Solve2 {
  final class Solve2Builder[A: ClassTag, B: ClassTag] {
    def build[X](implicit lub: Lub[A, B, X])
    : Solve2[A, B] { type C = X } = new Solve2[A, B] {
      type C = X
      val query: Any => C = _ match {
        case a: A => lub.ev1(a)
        case b: B => lub.ev2(b)
      } 
    }
  }
  def apply[A: ClassTag, B: ClassTag]: Solve2Builder[A, B] = new Solve2Builder[A, B]
}
```

Now the `Solve2[A, B]{ type C = ... }` is built using the builder created by the companion object, the implicit evidence for `A <:< C` and `B <:< C` has to be supplied only once:

```
val s2 = Solve2[Int, Float].build
val q2: Any => AnyVal = s2.query
```

Note that all these maneuvers with `ClassTag`s only take you so far: you will be able to distinguish between `Int` and `Float`, but you won't be able to distinguish between `List[Int]` and `List[Float]`. Before you investigate any further, you might take a closer look at what [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#type-safe-cast) has to offer.

Comment: Implicit evidence is unstable. I could not calculate it on the type level, i.e. without creating objects. `query` typing is not the goal but the solution I tried, but failed. If creating objects are allowed then the gist I mentioned offers fine solution

Comment: To distinguish `List[Int]` from `List[Float]` you could use `TypeTag`s

Comment: @ayvango Then I've misinterpreted your question, sorry. I'll delete my answer, so your question hopefully gets a bit more attention again.